# Converting string to element in Marklogic Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have the following XQuery script that basically adds properties to an existing document in MarkLogic:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error";
declare namespace cdata = "http://www.w3.org/1999/cdata";

declare variable $uri as xs:string external;
declare variable $contentproperties as xs:string external;

xdmp:document-add-properties($uri, ( $contentproperties ) );
```

The external C# program calls this query and passes in the following as string for the `$contentproperties`:

```
<Title>My Title</Title>,<Date>1629076218</Date>,<SubjectArea>My subject</SubjectArea>,<ContentType>My content type</ContentType>,<Summary>My summary</Summary>
```

However, an error returns mentioning that:

> XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:document-add-properties("", "My Title,1629076218,My ...") -- arg2 is not of type element()*"

How should I convert `xs:string` to `element()*` type?

Reference to the document-add-properties method: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-add-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`tokenize()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:tokenize) that string of comma separated values, then use [`xdmp:unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote) to parse the XML string into an XML document, and then XPath to the element. Assign that sequence of elements to another variable, and use that variable to set your properties:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace xhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error";
declare namespace cdata = "http://www.w3.org/1999/cdata";

declare variable $uri as xs:string external := "test";
declare variable $contentproperties as xs:string external := "<Title>My Title</Title>,<Date>1629076218</Date>,<SubjectArea>My subject</SubjectArea>,<ContentType>My content type</ContentType>,<Summary>My summary</Summary>";
declare variable $contentproperties-element as element()* := tokenize($contentproperties, ",") ! xdmp:unquote(.)/*;
xdmp:document-add-properties($uri, ( $contentproperties-element ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfect. There are some parts i do not understand -> ! xdmp:unquote(.)/* , what does the exclamation and the /* behind unquote do?

Comment: The exclamation is a simple map operator (it works kind of like a for loop) https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator, and the /* is an XPath to select the child element of the document-node that is returned from xdmp:unquote()